# Using a link instead of a button in beginform

Tags: .net, asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc-2, html.beginform

How do I use a link instead of a button to submit a form in beginform

This is what I have, but i dont wanna use a button

> ```
>            <% using (Html.BeginForm())
>              { %>
>              - <%: role %>
>              <%: Html.Hidden("Username", user) %>
>              <%: Html.Hidden("RoleToDelete", role) %>
>              <button type="submit">X</button>
>           <% } %>
> ```

Thanks

Comment: Does Html.ActionLink would work for you? see http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/11/13/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-1.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Add some javascript to the link:

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.nameofyourform.submit();">X</a>
```

You'd need some method of identifying your form so you can call its related object's submit method, such that your generated html looks something like:

```
<form id="myform" name="nameofyourform" action="..." method="...">
...
</form>
```

The id would let you do `document.getElementById('myform'.submit()`, and the name will work as in the `<a>` example above.

Of course, this all depends on Javascript. If you're targetting older/js-deprived browsers, the only way you'll be able to submit the form is via an actual submit button

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using MVC i assume you will also use JQuery:

```
<a href="#" onclick="$(this).parents('form').submit();" >Submit</a>
```

Drawbacks:

- doesn't work when pressing enter (workaround: keep the submit button but position it offscreen)
- doesn't work when JS disabled on browser

Answer (score 0):

You need to name your form first with BeginForm, then you can refernce it in the link's onclick event.

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "deletionform" }))
{ %>
- <%: role %>
<%: Html.Hidden("Username", user) %>
<%: Html.Hidden("RoleToDelete", role) %>
<a onclick="deletionform.submit();">X</button>
<% } %>
```